# STM32F4 Discovery the system clock configuration

Tags: c, arm, clock, stm32

I have to configure system clock on my STM32F4 Discovery board and I cannot get it right. I used "System clock configuraction" program from STM website ( http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF257927# ). I've set HCKL to 168 and generated source file with PPL(HSI) option and pasted it to my project, calling generated `SystemInit()` function. The generated source file in comments at its top indicates that ABP1 prescaler is set to 4. I've created a timer that should interrupt my program once a second:

```
NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_InitStructure;
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM5, ENABLE);

NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM5_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 2;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

TIM_InitStructure.TIM_Period = 168000000 / 4; // clockspeed/prescaler
TIM_InitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 0;
TIM_InitStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = 0;
TIM_InitStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM5, &TIM_InitStructure);
TIM_ITConfig(TIM5, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);
TIM_Cmd(TIM5, ENABLE);
```

However my `TIM5_IRQHandler` seems to be called every 0,5 second. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I wrote for that board that uses the pll at 168Mhz and the timer and interrupt (blah).  See if/how it compares to yours, I dont use their library

I highly recommend you start by polling first, get the system clock and timer configured one at thing at a time then get the interrupt as close to the core, clearing correctly, etc and the last step is to do an interrupt and handler.

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
void PUT16 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
unsigned int GET16 ( unsigned int );
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
#define RCCBASE   0x40023800
#define RCC_CR    (RCCBASE+0x00)
#define RCC_PLLCFGR (RCCBASE+0x04)
#define RCC_CFGR  (RCCBASE+0x08)
#define GPIODBASE 0x40020C00
#define TIM5BASE  0x40000C00
#define FLASH_ACR  0x40023C00
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
volatile unsigned int intcounter;
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
// CAREFUL, THIS IS AN INTERRUPT HANDLER
void tim5_handler ( void )
{
    intcounter++;
    PUT32(TIM5BASE+0x10,0x00000000);
}
// CAREFUL, THIS IS AN INTERRUPT HANDLER
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
void ClockInit ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;

    //enable HSE
    ra=GET32(RCC_CR);
    ra&=~(0xF<<16);
    PUT32(RCC_CR,ra);
    ra|=1<<16;
    PUT32(RCC_CR,ra);
    while(1)
    {
        if(GET32(RCC_CR)&(1<<17)) break;
    }
    PUT32(RCC_CFGR,0x00009401); //PPRE2 /2 PPRE1 /4 sw=hse

    //slow flash accesses down otherwise it will crash
    PUT32(FLASH_ACR,0x00000105);

    //8MHz HSE, 168MHz pllgen 48MHz pll usb
    //Q 7 P 2 N 210 M 5 vcoin 1 pllvco 336 pllgen 168 pllusb 48
    ra=(7<<24)|(1<<22)|(((2>>1)-1)<<16)|(210<<6)|(5<<0);
    PUT32(RCC_PLLCFGR,ra);

    // enable pll
    ra=GET32(RCC_CR);
    ra|=(1<<24);
    PUT32(RCC_CR,ra);

    //wait for pll lock
    while(1)
    {
        if(GET32(RCC_CR)&(1<<25)) break;
    }

    //select pll
    PUT32(RCC_CFGR,0x00009402); //PPRE2 /2 PPRE1 /4 sw=pllclk

    //if you didnt set the flash wait states you may crash here

    //wait for it to use the pll
    while(1)
    {
        if((GET32(RCC_CFGR)&0xC)==0x8) break;
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    unsigned int lastcount;
    unsigned int newcount;

    ClockInit();

    ra=GET32(RCCBASE+0x30);
    ra|=1<<3; //enable port D
    PUT32(RCCBASE+0x30,ra);

    ra=GET32(RCCBASE+0x40);
    ra|=1<<3; //enable TIM5
    PUT32(RCCBASE+0x40,ra);

    //d12 = d15 led outputs
    ra=GET32(GPIODBASE+0x00);
    ra&=0x00FFFFFF;
    ra|=0x55000000;
    PUT32(GPIODBASE+0x00,ra);
    //push pull
    ra=GET32(GPIODBASE+0x04);
    ra&=0xFFFF0FFF;
    PUT32(GPIODBASE+0x04,ra);

    //start with green led
    PUT32(GPIODBASE+0x18,0xE0001000);

    //setup timer
    PUT32(TIM5BASE+0x00,0x00000000);
    PUT32(TIM5BASE+0x2C,168000000/4); //auto reload
    PUT32(TIM5BASE+0x0C,0x00000001); //interrupt enable
    PUT32(TIM5BASE+0x10,0x00000000); //clear interrupt
    PUT32(TIM5BASE+0x00,0x00000001);

    intcounter = 0;
    //enable interrupt 50 TIM5
    PUT32(0xE000E104,0x00040000);

    lastcount = intcounter;
    while(1)
    {
        newcount=intcounter;
        if(lastcount!=newcount)
        {
            switch(lastcount&0x3)
            {
                case 0: PUT32(GPIODBASE+0x18,0xE0001000); break;
                case 1: PUT32(GPIODBASE+0x18,0xD0002000); break;
                case 2: PUT32(GPIODBASE+0x18,0xB0004000); break;
                case 3: PUT32(GPIODBASE+0x18,0x70008000); break;
            }
            lastcount=newcount;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Some notes I wrote about what I saw at the time:

TIM5 is actually a 32 bit counter not 16 like many of the others.  If
we count to 168,000,000 * 4 ticks that should be 4 seconds right?
Well we get 8 seconds per led blink.  I think what is going on is there
are two AHB divisors PPRE1 and PPRE2 with different speed limits.  To
keep PPRE2 at or under 84Mhz it wants a divide by 2, to keep PPRE1 under
42MHz it wants a divide by 4.  The clock tree diagram doesnt really show
these two divisors (that I can see) but it has a thing for the timers
where if divisor is non-zero then multiply by 2.  I assume what this all
means is PPRE1 which is a divide by 4 is multiplied by 2 to feed the
timers.  And that appears to match, if you change PPRE1 to divide by 8
and the it takes 16 seconds for the led to change.

So I saw it being too long, you are seeing it be too short by a power of 2?  I am using the external source you are using internal?